# How to install a specified bundle (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jackson, bundle

I am new to Eclipse plug-in development. I downloaded a completed source code of an Eclipse plug-in. When I tried to export it and install it in my local Eclipse, I encountered an "Install job" problem:

```
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. ** requires 'bundle com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

In MANIFEST.MF:

```
Require-Bundle: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core,
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind
```

I guess the problem would be solved if I can install `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core`, but I am wondering how can I install it?

Environment:

- Windows 10 64-bits
- Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install it would be from [Eclipse Orbit](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170919201930/).

1. Open the install manager (*Help > Install New Software....*)
2. Put the relevant Orbit site as location
3. Check the plugin in question
4. Walk through the wizard to finish the installation